# Python error : SyntaxError: invalid syntax. How to solve this?

Tags: python

```
    #create a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = [
        'Oregon': 'OR',
        'Florida': 'FL',
        'California': 'CA',
        'New York': 'NY',
        'Michigan': 'MI'
]

# create a basic set of states and some cities in them
cities = [
        'CA': 'San Francisco',
        'MI': 'Detroit',
        'FL': 'Jacksonville'
]
,
#add someor more cities
cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

#rprint out some citis
print '-' * 10
print "NY state has: ", cities['NY']
print "OR state has: ", cities['OR']

#print some states
print '-' * 10
print "Michigan's abbreviation is: ", states['Michigan']
print "Florida's abbreviation is: ", states['Florida']
```

Stored this code in ex39_dictionaries.py. When I execute it, I see below error. Whats wrong with this code ?

File "ex39_dictionaries.py", line 3
    'Oregon': 'OR',
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If the code's purpose is to throw a syntax error, then it's working perfectly. What do you think the code is supposed to do?

Comment: And dictionaries are defined with curly braces, not brackets.

Comment: Thanks @DavyM, using curly braces solved the error.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html Read dictionaries section.

Answer (score 1):

```
states = [
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
]
```

Using square brackets, this is an attempt to define a *list*, and list items must be separated with commas. However, it seems that you want to create a *dictionary* here (i.e. a collection of `key: value` pairs), and for that braces (curly brackets) must be used:

```
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}
```

Comment: *Angular brackets* would usually refer to something like `<...>`; I think you meant *square brackets*.